# ECONOMY MODE- DRIVE

Tags: honda

I recently purchased a Honda vehicle and been driving in ECO mode. I wonder if ECO mode really boosts the MPG of a vehicle. As I do not see any effect. Neither I am not reaching close to the proposed MPG as well.
Any Idea?

Comment: Which Honda did you purchase? Does it have CVT? My wife's new Honda has ECO and CVT and she ran into the same thing.

Comment: It will depend on your driving style : hard acceleration, gentle, heavy braking, anticipation etc etc etc As for proposed mpg, do you use the same test track or do your road conditions traffic, hills etc differ?